# LPDHCPCAPI_CLASSID C++ DhcpRequestParams

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dhcp

I was trying to figure out how to get vendor specific data using DhcpRequestParams and can't figure out how to use the LPDHCPCAPI_CLASSID provided this documentation. Before I was just using NULL to use this method.

[documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363298.aspx)

I guess the solution would be figuring out how to turn a string into this value? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Doing some more reading and looking back at what I was doing, I guess what I need is to be able to get an option from a different said vendor. The class ID should be the same I believe, I had been reading elsewhere that someone was trying to workaround with different class ID but that shouldn't have to be done. So I need to know how to receive dhcp option response, provided a request, from a different vendor, if possible.

Comment: `LPDHCPCAPI_CLASSID` is optional, maybe you don't need it? Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363345.aspx for a good example of using `DhcpRequestParams`

Comment: I can get all MS vendor specific, but I made a custom option and cannot pull it with this. I can get any MS vendor specific by opting out with null and false classID, but not sure how to get something that is defined as vendor specific.